# How to get folder path and filename after upload php?

Tags: php

I have a simple section in which user upload files to a folder named videos, now I want to get the path to this folder.

Files are uploaded to this path

```
/public_html/editorv1/videos/
```

Now I want to get this path eg

```
/editorv1/videos/video1.mp4
```

I tried this

```
$filePath = realpath($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Which give me this

```
/home/klient.dhosting.pl/videomill/.tmp/phpmJQvlwthats_great.mp4
```

What do I need to change to get what  I want?

Comment: use move_uploaded_file: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm

Comment: what does $_SERVER[' [DOCUMENT_ROOT'] gives?

Answer (score 0):

If `/public_html` is a fixed constant that's always at the beginning you can just remove that part of the string with something like:

```
define('FOLDER_PREFIX', '/public_html');

$filePath = substr($filePath, strlen(FOLDER_PREFIX) );
```

Otherwise you can use [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find the 2nd path separator and then use [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) like above.

Comment: `substr() expects at least 2 parameters`

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a file it is save on a temporary location until you move it(save it).

You need to move that uploaded file to your desired folder.

```
$filename = 'video1.mp4';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/editorv1/videos/' .$filename )
```

This will save your file to your desired location, you also need to validate the file type, size and for errors uploading.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi when I save file they go to /editorv1/videos, I can see those files direct to folder I want them to be I think I dont need to move any file

Comment: you change your temp file location to be /editorv1/videos ?

Comment: what you are seeing with ```realpath``` is the temp location of the file with a temporary file name. That's why you need to move it to your desired location.